# Using App Engine Task Queue Within Pyramid

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pyramid

Configuration of the Task Queue is done in the app.yaml file. There I have:

```
- url: /_ah/queue/default
  script: task.py
```

Normally, task.py would be found when calling taskqueue.add()
Unfortunately, when using Pyramid I get a 404 in the log, and I'm guessing that has to do with the previous line:

```
- url: .*
  script: runner.py
```

This runs the app-engine monkey and associated files to run pyramid. Is there a way I can change this so that my root would still be handled by Pyramid, but /_ah/queue/default by task.py?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reverse the order of these two lines? The wildcard url should always be at the bottom of the list.

Comment: Thanks! I feel incredibly stupid for asking this. I know I tried this earlier, but must have had something else wrong at that time.